# Reverse vs Reverse! in Ruby when comparing palindrome

Tags: ruby, string

I know that ***reverse*** creates a new string with the characters of the string in reverse and that ***reverse!*** mutates (reverses) the current string in place. My question is why, when for example testing for a palindrome, this occurs?:

```
a = "foobar"
a == a.reverse    # => false
a == a.reverse!   # => true
```

Is it because it is the same object in memory, therefore == just checks if they have the same memory location?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes reverse! change string it self and use the same memory allocation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`String#reverse!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-reverse-21) method returns the string it is called on so

```
a == a.reverse!
```

is the same as saying

```
a.reverse!
a == a
```

and of course `a == a` is true.

Note that it doesn't matter in the least what `reverse!` does to the string, what matters to `==` in `o == o.m` is what the method (`m`) returns.

Answer (score 4):

```
a == a.reverse!   # => true
```

Is because `a.reverse!` is executed before comparision.

`a.reverse!` performs internal string reversing. After this operation is done, `a` became a string, containing `raboof`. Since `String#reverse!` returned the result of reversion, the strings (`raboof` on the left side as soon as `a` was already changed by call to `#reverse!`, and `raboof` on the right side as a result of call to `reverse!`) are being compared using `#eql?`, resulting in `true`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I got stuck into this line _Returns whether str == obj, similar to `Object#==`_. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can run a check on object_id to make sure **!**(bang) overwrites self.

```
 > a.object_id
 => 64561940 

 > a.reverse.object_id
 => 61943060 

 > a.reverse!.object_id
 => 64561940
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `String#reverse!` changes value of a `a` variable, but `String#reverse` return new value without change `a` variable.